# PHP: выводит в строке "\'" вместо "'"

Tags: php, строки

Здравствуйте. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Есть следующий код:

```
$str = "";
$total = count($rows);
$counter = 0;
foreach ($rows as $item) {
  $out[$item['id']] = $item;
  $counter++;
  if($counter == 1) {
    $str .= $item['id']."'".",";
  }
  if($counter == $total){
    $str .= "'".$item['id'];
  }
  else{
    $str .= "'".$item['id']."'".",";
  }
```

В строку должны записываться ID, разделяясь , и ' (первая и последняя кавычка ставится автоматически). Вот только результат получается вот такой:

> '72142\',\'72142\',\'72133\',\'67568\',\'67115\',\'67163\',\'67165\',\'67199\',\'67222\',\'67240\',\'67321\',\'67334\',\'67427\',\'72113\',\'82066\',\'81981\',\'73940\',\'66886\',\'66875\',\'66843\',\'66824\',\'66810\',\'66798\',\'72193\',\'66482\',\'66475\',\'66473\',\'66462\',\'66448\',\'66437\',\'66435'

А нужно, чтобы получилось вот так:

> '72142','72142','72133','67568','67115','67163','67165','67199','67222','67240','67321','67334','67427','72113','82066','81981','73940','66886','66875','66843','66824','66810','66798','72193','66482','66475','66473','66462','66448','66437','66435'

Не понимаю, почему выводит кавычку вместе со слешом.

Comment: а куда выводит-то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не извращайтесь с циклами, для этого хорошо работает функциональный стиль.

- [array_map](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php) - каждый элемент массива отобразить в новый массив, как результат вызова функции
- [implode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php) - склеить элементы массива с помощью разделителя

Пример:

```
$rows = [13, 132, 834];

echo implode(',', array_map(function($row){
    return "'{$row}'";
}, $rows));

// '13','132','834'
```

[Демонстрация](https://3v4l.org/j09mt)

C id:

```
$rows = [['id' => 13], ['id' => 132], ['id' => 834]];
$out = array_reduce($rows, function($res, $row){
  $res[$row['id']] = $row;
  return $res;
}, []);
$str = implode(',', array_map(function($row){
    return "'{$row['id']}'";
}, $rows));
echo $str . "\n";
echo json_encode($out);
```

Вывод:

> '13','132','834'
>   {"13":{"id":13},"132":{"id":132},"834":{"id":834}}

[Демонстрация](https://3v4l.org/9TvBL)

*По поводу проблемы из вопроса, думаю она надумана, вы выводите результат в каком-нибудь `var_dump`, который экранирует кавычки для корректного отображения. Также, никаких автоматических апострофов там нет, это просто формат вывода*

Comment: array (
  0 => 13,
  1 => 132,
  2 => 834,
) примерно так выводит ваша запись, а мне надо вытащить конкретно числа

Comment: https://3v4l.org/j09mt

Comment: Разобралась. Спасибо. Оказывается и правда проблема надумана и это особенности вывода функции file_put_contents('si.txt', var_export( $rows, true));

Comment: Добавил чуть более приближенный к вашему вариант, с id в массивах и собиранием `$out`